# Scala add extension method when the type params have a common type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-level-computation

I have a type `Foo[+A, +B]` and a type `Bar[+B]`. I want to add extension method `bar` to `Foo` like this

```
implicit class FooSyntax[A](foo: Foo[A, Bar[A]]) {
   def bar: A = ???
}
```

So the extension method is only applicable when `B` is a `Bar[A]`. And thus all of the following should compile —

```
trait Fruit
trait Apple  extends Fruit
trait Banana extends Fruit
def foo0: Foo[Apple, Bar[Banana]] = ???
def foo1: Foo[Apple, Bar[String]] = ???
def foo2: Foo[Apple, Bar[Apple]]  = ???
def foo3: Foo[Apple, List[Apple]] = ???

foo0.bar // Fruit
foo1.bar // Object
foo2.bar // Apple
```

For my use-case I want to be able to do this without `FooSyntax` using an implicit requirement, that way the method is always available and is easy to discover, however calling it is only possible when the type condition is satisfied. This is what I have come so far —

```scala
trait Foo[+A, +B] {
    def bar[C <: A](implicit evA: A <:< C, evB: B <:< Bar[C]): C
}
```

Needless to say, this doesn't work.

Comment: I want the method to be available always for better discoverability but calling it should only be possible when the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

```scala
trait Foo[+A, +B] {
  def bar(implicit ev: FooBar[A, B]): ev.Out
}

trait Bar[+B]

trait FooBar[-A, -B] {
  type Out
}

object FooBar {
  type Aux[A] = FooBar[A, Bar[A]] { type Out = A }

  implicit def x[A]: FooBar.Aux[A] =
    new FooBar[A, Bar[A]] {
      override type Out = A
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the type bound from `C` and just leave the implicit evidence to do its job.

```scala
trait Bar[+B]

trait Foo[+A, +B] {
  def bar[C](implicit ev1: A <:< C, ev: B <:< Bar[C]): C = ???
}
```

Then you can do this *(as expected)*:

```scala
foo0.bar // Fruit
foo1.bar // Object
foo2.bar // Apple
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/7H8icAsPS7SzEqiY6V1ZIA/6)*

Comment: Why doesn't the same work in `scala 2.13.x`?

Comment: @JohnyTKoshy ah, my bad. I forgot **Scastie** uses **Scala 3** by default. Uhm, the type inference algorithm was improved in `3.0.0` it seems the old version is unable to do what you want.

Comment: It's not my question. OP may be using `3.0.0`. I was trying the same in `2.13.x`. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to make it work in Scala `2.13.7`